# How to get the real-time memory usage of system when a function is now executing?

Tags: php

I have an image reader like below:

```
    $file = "XXX.jpg";
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage($file);
    $type = $image->getImageFormat();
    $image->setFormat($type);

    ...

    echo $image->getImagesBlob();
```

If I want to get the real-time memory usage of the system at the moment the `echo $image->getImagesBlob();` is executing, how should I do? Is it possible to run PHP code asynchronously?

Comment: So, let's say you manage to monitor what you want to, from PHP (wrong place to monitor from). What would you do then? Deny requests?